# Keeping the resolution of a plot but condensing the size in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a plot that I am generating in `R` that needs to be in .pdf format. The current code that I am using is the following:

```
x1 = seq(0,1,.001)
x2 = seq(0,1,.001)

f = function(x1,x2){
  ans = x1 + x2
  return(ans)
}

h = function(x1,x2){
  ans1 = 1.5-x1-2*x2-.5*sin(2*pi*(x1^2-2*x2))
  ans2 = x1^2+x2^2-1.5
  ans1 = sapply(ans1,function(x){max(x,0)})
  ans2 = sapply(ans2,function(x){max(x,0)})
  ans = ans1 + ans2
  return(ans)
}

z = outer(x1,x2,f)
w = outer(x1,x2,h)

image(x1,x2,z,xlab=expression(x[1]),ylab=expression(x[2]))
contour(x1,x2,z,add=TRUE)

X = cbind(expand.grid(x1,x2),c(w))
points(X[X[,3]!=0,1],X[X[,3]!=0,2],pch=19,col="lightgrey")
```

Now the plot looks exactly as I would like for it to be, however, when I go to save the plot as a .pdf the size of the file is around 60 MB which is far to large for me to place into a document (let alone it takes quite sometime to even open). Is there a way to modify my code to keep the plot looking the same, but having the file size be much smaller?

I understand that the problem is because I plot so many points, however, I am not sure how to generate the nice "smooth" grey area without doing so. Perhaps there is a simple command to use that I am unaware of.

Comment: Do you need vector graphics or would a PNG do instead?

Comment: Unfortunately vector.

Comment: I recently ran into the same problem. There's no way to compress a vector graphic, if I'm right. Consider Roland's suggestion, or consider a jpeg which may look smoother. Another way would be to blur your variances a little to an amount that's sufficient for printing, e.g. rather `0.000 0.005 0.010 0.015...` than `0.000 0.001 0.002 0.003...`.

Comment: I'd expect a journal to accept a PNG (possibly embedded in a PDF) of sufficient resolution. Vector graphics really is not the right tool for this.

Comment: What about options for rewriting the code? Say, instead of using points are there other commands that I could use to get the same graphic that would take up less space? For example, say, using polygon (not sure how that would work in this context) instead of points?