# How to save a picture drew by image function into pdf format in Rstudio?

Tags: r, figure

I used image drawing a figure, which I want to save into pdf file. But the figure with slight gradient colour in the pdf file, but not in the .png file (if I choose the .png format). 
Well, I need the pdf to keep the figure clear after I zoom in, so how can I save the figure drawing by the image into pdf file?

Comment: Would jpg be an option? Should be better suited for gradients.

Comment: @jay.sf jpg is the same as .png, right? Both of them are unclear after zoom in.

Comment: There was a similar question before. Is the reason you won't use `pdf()` the resulting bis size?

Comment: @jay.sf sorry, i did get it. could you show me the question? Thanks!

Comment: Could you give us some code? What have you tried, and what do you try to achieve?

Comment: @IvyGao [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53424623/6574038) it is.

Comment: @jay.sf thanks! and AkselA probability like jay says, they is no way to do so.